What is the meaning of $p_{g_i}$ in this equation?
I am reading "The element of statistical learning" and having some question regarding equation 2.36. The book stated that:
"A more interesting example is the multinomial likelihood for the regression function $Pr(G|X)$ for a qualitative output $G$. Suppose we have a model
$Pr(G=\mathcal{G}_{k}|X=x)=p_{k,\theta}(x),\,k=1,\ldots,K$ for the conditional probability of
each class given $X$, indexed by the parameter vector $\theta$. Then the
log-likelihood (also referred to as the cross-entropy) is
$$L(\theta)=\sum_{i=1}^{N}\log p_{g_{i},\theta}(x_{i}), \tag{2.36}$$
and when maximized it delivers values of $\theta$ that best conform with the data in this
likelihood sense"
Can someone explain to me what is the "conditional probability of each class given $X$"? And what is the meaning of the variable $p_{{g_i},\theta}(x_i)$ which has never been mentioned earlier in the book?
